# How do I modify a libreoffice impress layout?

Tags: layout, libreoffice, presentation

I just received a new slide to work with; it was created with powerpoint, so, I naturally converted it to impress. The master page was converted alright, background is correct, items positioned in the right places but now I need to adapt the current slide layouts to work with the master template. The default positioning for the layouts are not compatible with the master page. The title, per example, gets misplaced above the logo. 
So, here is my question: how do I change the default layouts for my presentation? I want to change the default position for the text components in a way that it is reusable.

Answer (score 2):

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/29811/is-libreoffice-compatible-with-microsoft-office-2007-and-2010-word-excel-powerpoint-publisher/

recommends upload to Google docs for conversion.